# Google Cloud Build - source-context.json SHA mismatch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-build

I have a Python 3 project which I am hosting on Google AppEngine Standard. Until a couple of days ago I was able to deploy normally (right since I did the initial setup in July 2019) until a couple of days ago. Now I get the following response:

```
starting build "abc"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetcher"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetcher": Fetching manifest gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com/ae/xxx/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Processing 312 files.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Failed to fetch gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com/xxx, will no longer retry: fetching "gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com/xxx" with timeout 1h0m0s to temp file "/workspace/.download/staging.my-project.appspot.com-xxx": source-context.json SHA mismatch, got "xxx", want "yyy"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Failed to download at least one file. Cannot continue.
Finished Step #0 - "fetcher"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Any idea why this would be happening and how to fix it?

P.S. I use the following command for deployment:

```
gcloud --project my-project app deploy app.yaml
```

Comment: Hi, could you open this issue under this [Public Issue Tracker component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491299) specifying your project name so we could investigate this from our side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After conversation with Google engineers (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154588981?pli=1) the following worked:

1. Remove the `source-context.json` file
2. Delete the bucket where the deployment files are, e.g. gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com
3. Deploy again

If you need the `source-context.json` file, you can follow these steps: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/source-context&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNHMB7Dm_jISwG2AnpokQ7XN5GmLAw

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did and it worked for me:

1.
Go to the link that in the error description:

[image]

2.
You'll see there some lines for staging fail, copy the name of the file in the first line:

[image]

3.
Go to the Google storage [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) and enter to a bucket with name that starts with "staging.***"
And inside that bucket I search for the string I copy in step 2:

[image]

4.
Deleted that file, and retry that steps for every line you'll see in the error details link (in my example there are 4 rows).

[image]

5.
Deploy again!

Comment: thanks for this amazing answer. The error logs aren't descriptive enough to help users debug properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after I changed a local file during a `gcloud app deploy` with a long upload (2200 files, because of a wrong .gcloudignore).

I fixed it by deleting the changed file in the [cloud storage browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/staging.interactive-consultant.appspot.com;tab=objects), and deploying again with `gcloud app deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a NextJS project the solution may be to delete the `.next` folder and rebuild your project. It seems the some of the cache files from next can become out of sync.

From the root of your project:

`rm -rf .next && next build`

then redeploy as usual